# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'elasticsearch' in Dataproc Serverless Pyspark job

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-dataproc-serverless

I am trying to use elastic search package in Dataproc Serverless Spark pyspark job. I am facing issue only with this package in Dataproc Serverless.

```
import os
print("Current dir:", os.getcwd())
print("Current dir list:", os.listdir('.'))
 
import pandas
import statsmodels
import platform
import numpy
 
print("Python version:", platform.python_version())
print("Pandas version:", pandas.__version__)
print("statsmodel version:", statsmodels.__version__ )
print("Numpy version:", numpy.__version__)

#import elasticsearch as es
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch as es
print("elasticsearch version:", es.__version__ )
```

Below is the output for this code.

```
Current dir: /tmp/srvls-batch-7554fe27-4044-4341-ae79-ffe9488ea385
Current dir list: ['pyspark_venv.tar.gz', '.test_sls.py.crc', 'test_sls.py']
Python version: 3.9.15
Pandas version: 1.4.4
statsmodel version: 0.13.5
Numpy version: 1.21.6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/srvls-batch-7554fe27-4044-4341-ae79-ffe9488ea385/test_sls.py", line 16, in <module>
    from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch as es
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'elasticsearch'
```

I followed below steps to setup venv for this job,

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/python_packaging.html#using-virtualenv

and used --archives option while calling the job. Can anyone please correct me, if I am missing anything. Thanks in advance

Comment: May you share full `gcloud` command that you used to submit your job (excluding sensitive information, if any)?

Comment: gcloud dataproc batches submit --project <project name> --region us-central1 pyspark <python file path>  --archives <python packages tar file location> --container-image <image> --version 1.0 --subnet <subnet> --service-account <service account> --properties spark.driver.cores=4,spark.dynamicAllocation.executorAllocationRatio=0.3,spark.executor.cores=4

Hi @IgorDvorzhak Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 1):

When providing custom Python env (via `--archives` or container image), you need to configure Spark to use it, instead of the default one.

To do this, you need to set [`PYSPARK_PYTHON` env var to point to Python binary in the custom Python env](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc-serverless/docs/guides/custom-containers#python_packages).

It can be done in container image script, or via Spark properties:

- `spark.dataproc.driverEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=...`
- `spark.executorEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=...`

Comment: PYSPARK_PYTHON=./environment/bin/python
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/temurin-11-jdk-amd64
SPARK_EXTRA_CLASSPATH=/opt/spark/jars/*
:: loading settings :: file = /etc/spark/conf/ivysettings.xml
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "./environment/bin/python": error=2, No such file or directory
 at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
 at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)


Getting file not found error, I verified the path and file exists

Comment: is this error expected ?

Comment: How do you know that `./environment/bin/python` is a correct path to the Python binary in new Python env?

Comment: If I am not defining, below paramaters,

spark.dataproc.driverEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON
spark.executorEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON

Then I can see in the working directory, I can see 'environment' directory is getting  copied. The path what I mentioned exists. Were you able to trigger a batch job with similar requirement.

Comment: Seems like the issue is that `./environment/bin/python` is a symlink to the `/usr/bin/python` that does not exist inside the container. I think that adding `apt install python-is-python3` command during container creation may solve this issue.

Comment: Hi Igor, Tried the same and just wanted to show that we are using an image where python binaries are installed in /usr/bin/python, but facing same issue. Unfortunately no luck :( 

spark@38af63f15849:/$ ls -lrt /usr/bin/python*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5479736 Feb 28  2021 /usr/bin/python3.9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Mar  2  2021 /usr/bin/python -> python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Apr  5  2021 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.9

Comment: I think that you need to make sure that in your local environment that you use to create venv, Python binary is also available in the `/usr/bin/python` path (i.e. both your local env and container must us the same Python binary path). May you check this with `which python` in your local env?